# Render the point shapefile and raster layer together as single image

Tags: qgis, shapefile, raster-conversion, vector-layer, mrsid

I have a point layer as one shapefile and MrSid file as raster layer. How to overlap these two layers and clip the merged layer and render it as an output image file?

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS - Turn both layers on - File > Import/Export > Export Map to Image

Set your view to the map extent that you want and voila

But im also guessing that perhaps you are wanting something more specific, like a specific output file format, or a geographically located output raster dataset, so perhaps update your question wit some more info on this and we can help